# Where are IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks and IGoogleApiClientOnConnectionFailedListener defined?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build an application using Xamarin and I want to use G+ button in App. I also added Google Play Services Component still not able to build successfully.

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Taap    C:\Users\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Taap\Taap\MainActivity.cs   18  Active

Comment: Please suggest what I am missing to import in my project!

Answer (score 0):

In your Taap\MainActivity.cs add and implement both of those interfaces to/within your Activity:

### Example:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
```

#### Implement `IConnectionCallbacks`:

```
void OnConnected (Bundle connectionHint);

void OnConnectionSuspended (int cause);
```

Note: This is in the `Android.Gms.Common.Apis` namespace

```
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
```

#### Implement `IOnConnectionFailedListener`

```
void OnConnectionFailed (ConnectionResult result);
```

Note: This is in `Android.Gms.Common` namespace:

```
using Android.Gms.Common;
```